# Write a Validator Class in Django-rest-framework that has access to the validatated_data

Tags: python, django, validation, rest, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to have a Validator Class in Django-rest-framework that has access to the validatated_data?

In particular, to check a relationship that using a `Validator Class` based upon the submitted data.

It can be put in the `serializer.create()` or `serializer.update()` where `validated_data` is an argument, but is it possible to put it as a `Validator` in the `meta` like:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ...
        validators = [MyClassValidator(... that has access to validated_data...)]
```

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#writing-custom-validators

Answer (score 2):

The Key for this to work is to use the `set_context` method for the *Django Rest Framework* `Validator Class` in order to gain access to the **validated_data**. The data will be an attribute on the `self.instance` when injected into the `MyValidator Class` below.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#class-based

Here is the `Validator Class`:

**validators.py:**

```
class MyValidator(object):

    def __init__(self, items, message=None):
        ...

    def __call__(self, kwargs):
        ...

    def set_context(self, serializer):
        """
        This hook is called by the serializer instance,
        prior to the validation call being made.
        """
        # Determine the existing instance, if this is an update operation.
        self.instance = getattr(serializer, 'instance', None)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        validators = [MyValidator('items')]
        fields = (...)
```